# Unity slow on  Ubuntu 12.04 with ATI X1250 graphics card

Tags: unity, radeon

I have an HP 6715b with ATI X1250 graphics card. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I observe that Unity is running slowly. Is that normal?

My system configuration is: 4GB RAM and AMD Turion x2 1.9 GHz processor.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

After it gets installed, type `htop` and see what process is consuming the most RAM and CPU. You have to observe it and judge whether it a necessary one or not.

If you find any process/application as behaving abnormally (by consuming more RAM, CPU)  that is the cause of problem. Report the memory intensive process as a bug/problem.

Comment: Some processes normally use lots of RAM (or CPU). If you've never heard of a process, it's advisable to ask if this is normal, before [reporting a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). While Ask Ubuntu is not the place for bug reports, questions about whether or not something is a bug (when there is serious doubt) are generally considered on-topic.

Comment: Nope! Ram and CPU comsumption is normal! 10% Memory and Cpu when IDLE... But multitask is a pain... and unity still runs slow... with preload.. :S

Comment: So I think you have to report bug to launched.net